# How to download a file with Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.0.3 to create an application which delivers Excel files that should be downloadable by the user.

```
 response().setContentType("application/x-download");  
 response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=tradeLogTest.xlsx");
```

but,how to get the outputstream from `response()`？tks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Play's action can return a File:

```
response().setContentType("application/x-download");  
response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=tradeLogTest.xlsx"); 
return ok(new File("/absolute/path/to/tradeLogTest.xlsx"));
```

[Here's an API for Results](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/mvc/Results.html)

Comment: In Scala there is a shortcut : Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File(myFile)). Maybe it's the same for Java

Comment: [Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaStream) are the official docs for @JulienLafont's shortcut.

Comment: Does it support resume?

Comment: how is it possible to force for example chrome, to open the file (if PDF) with its internal PDF viewer?

Comment: @behzad use `content-disposition inline` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395151/1066240) anyway keep in mind that finally browser determines how to handle files (display or download)

Comment: thanks @biersior! I also have another question! what will happen if I do not set the ContentType? I tried it and it worked fine. for example I didnt set the ContentType, once I uploaded a .exe file, once a .pdf and for downloading, both chrome and IE handled them fine.

Comment: That depends from browser, they will just exec default action... while in this question asked for exactly opposite solution - download file instead opening

Answer (score 7):

Providing download option for static files can be done in Play as:

```
Ok.sendFile(new File("path to file/abc.csv"), inline=true).withHeaders(CACHE_CONTROL->"max-age=3600",CONTENT_DISPOSITION->"attachment; filename=abc.csv", CONTENT_TYPE->"application/x-download");
```

There are other parameters that are also available

For Internet Explorer - make sure you set the Content Disposition

Answer (score 0):

Serving files
If it’s not a problem to load the whole content into memory for simple content what about a large data set? Let’s say we want to send back a large file to the web client.

read more at : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaStream