# Play Framework: Controller action runs every load

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

Does anyone know why my action runs every time I reload a page. I have a page with a button that should run when I click on it. But now it seems to run when I load the page.

Here is my button and javascript in file *deliverables.scala.html*

```
<input type="button" class="btn success" id="add" value="Export to Excel" onclick="JavaScript:generateExcelClick()" />

<script>
function generateExcelClick(event)
{
   window.location = "@Application.generateExcel(currentPage)";
}
</script>
```

And my controller:

```
public static void generateExcel(List<Infoobject> list) {
    ...creating a file (works)
    ...No return
}
```

How can I change this code so it only runs when I click on the button? The action should not render an another page or something like that. I only want to generate a file.

Thanks!

**Edit**

I've tried @controllers.Application.generateExcel(currentPage); and @Application.generateExcel(currentPage); in my Javascript function, but it's still creating the file even if I don't click the button.

I have also checked that @Application.generateExcel(currentPage); doesn't runs from an another site och function.

Someone, please?

Comment: The question was why the `generateExcel(List<Infoobject> list)` runs every single page load. So I don't understand your answer.

Comment: No, sry for bad explaining. The file _"mydata.xls"_ is created even if I don't click on the button. It is created every time I enter deliverables site.

Comment: I've tried `@controllers.Application.generateExcel(currentPage);` in my Javascript function, but it's still creating the file even if I don't click the button. Gaaaaah!

Answer (score 1):

A little explanation:

When writing in your Scala view and you say

```
@Application.generateExcel(currentPage)
```

It runs the function `generateExcel` in controller `Application`

**What to do**

You don't want it to run the function immediately. You want it to go there `onClick`

So use

```
@routes.Application.generateExcel(currentPage)
```

This outputs a link to that function

However for this to work there has to be a (GET) link to that function in your `routes`

Add this to routes

```
GET  /whatever/:thing                 controllers.Application.generateExcel(thing: List<path.InfoObject> list)
```

**HOWEVER**

This is a bad idea.Why?
Because putting your entire list in a URL just isn't nice.

1. Do you ever see a complex list in a URL
2. URLs have to be less than 2000 characters

**WHAT TO DO INSTEAD**

Send the list as a POST data. Depending on how you take in your data you'll have to figure it out

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. The route code that you suggested doesn't work (I had to try, even if it sounds as a bad solution)

`(thing: List<path.InfoObject> list)` Error: "`)' expected but `<' found"...think it has to be [] instead of <>.

`thing: List[path.InfoObject] list` Error: "`)' expected but `l' found"...

`thing: List[path.InfoObject]` Error: "not found: value path"...no further ideas.

I will try the POST solution.

Comment: No That wouldn't be quite right... Maybe we can help you? The real question is how is this generated? Is it static data? Is it a form a user fills?

Comment: "currentPage" is a List of 'Infoobject'. On the deliverables site, there is a table that shows this list. Infoobject has designation, description, id and so on. There is a 'Export to Excel' button, when I click on it I want to generate a excel file. Why can't it just be simple like...Button>OnClick>Generate File? Why do I have to do it in a POST/GET?

Comment: Try this in the route instead `thing: java.util.List<models.InfoObject>` (if InfoObject is contained in the models package otherwise whatever package its in)

Comment: My guess would be routes doesn't support generic T-Lists.. You could just have `java.util.List` But then in your controller do `generateExcel(List l) {List<Infoobject> list=(List<Infoobject>) l;....`

Comment: `GET  /generate/  controllers.Application.generateExcel(list: java.util.List)` gets error: "trait List takes type parameters". Is this right approach to do this?

Comment: Try `GET /generate/ controllers.Application.generateExcel(list: java.util.ArrayList)`

Comment: "class ArrayList takes type parameters"

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just call a controller when clicking on a button, you could try :

```
<a href="@routes.YourController.YourMethod(args)"><button>Mybutton</button></a>
```

I don't think you need javascript here (if I understood your situation).

**Edit:** The idea of this answer is to say that the less javascript in your page, the better.

**Edit2 :** Can't comment the discussion below, so I put it here:
As I said here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521308/routing-in-java-play-framework-2-list-as-parameter/17522009#17522009), your have to declare your object like this :

`controllers.Application.method(list : java.util.List[your.package.Infoobject])`

Replace `your.package` with the package in which your object is (maybe `models`)

But you will get an errror : `No QueryString binder found for type`

This is because you can only put Strings and numerals in URLS, so the framework tells you to transform your Object (List) in a String (with the QueryStringBinder).

Comment: Edited my answer, to react to discussion below

Answer (score 0):

I would call routes-> /generateExcelReport from the button/link and make it return the file

[How to send a file to browser for downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559304/how-to-send-a-file-to-browser-for-downloading)

[How to download a file with Play Framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917105/how-to-download-a-file-with-play-framework-2-0)