# how to configure server to make link open not download at client

Tags: server-side-scripting

ok i was reading/watching or something few days ago and came across this trick. Which said that it tells browser to not prompt to download but instead open it or try to.

I forgot where i read about it or what it told.

I just know it was about url or headers.

Comment: Your question is too vague. As far as I know, you should setup MIME types on your server side first, but it depends on the Web Server you use

Comment: i think i just found out it has to do something with header called how to configure server to `Content-Disposition`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment

Answer (score 0):

You have to set http header called Content-Disposition to attachment or inline.

`"content-disposition" : "inline;filename=somefile.ext")`