# Linking a .doc file on a mvc view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word

For something which seems so simple I can't find a solution, I have a word .doc file which I want to be linked on one of my pages so that a user can click on a link and open/download it (whichever is easier) and then read it on the machine with MS word.

Right now I have it in my content folder and tried to display it in both an  and  but no luck.

Is this an issue of IIS or just I'm going about this all wrong?

Present dir setup:-

Solution>Project>Content>File.doc

Solution>Project>Views>Home>NewRecord.cshtml
File location 1st followed by page I'm trying to display file on.

Comment: <A href="content/word.docx">Word file </A>? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I've tried that but it navigates away from the page saying the resource cannot be found.

Comment: @tereško I had thought I'd selected that so I must of miss clicked.

Comment: then you are linking it incorrectly

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee If I drag the file from the folder onto the page I get (<a href="../../Content/C%20A%20-%20L.doc">C A - L.doc</a>), I have also tried (<a href="Content/CA-L.doc">C A - L.doc</a>) with 1st option getting a parser error and 2nd saying not found.

Comment: try <A href="filename.doc">File</a>

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Same issue :(

Comment: I need to see your directory structure. Can you post it here. The whole directory structure and files of the Cotnetn folder

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I've edited my question with the present dir setup for the file and for the view I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly that you want to make User to Click and he/she will be promoted to download the .doc then.....

You can achieve with submit button which will be styled with CSS as LINK, then you perform the HTTP GET to the server within HTML form tag, Form will target the action on Server, which will return **FileContentResult**,

```
    public FileContentResult GetWordDocument(string Id)
    {
            var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = "WordDoc.doc",
                Inline = false;
            };
            FileContentResult documentResult= File(secureDoc.SecuredFileBytes,"application/msword", contentDisposition.FileName);
            documentResult.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
            return documentResult;
    }
```

[Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.108).aspx

Hope this will help to resolve.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more basic as I only want to link them 1 local word file so since nothing was working with <a> I just uploaded the document onto intranet then hyperlinked to that as there's no issue opening it that way. If you can come up with a quicker simpler solution then I'll mark it correct otherwise I'll have to go with my work around which I hate.

Comment: What is the root issue? Can you quickly check that the Content[with .doc]  is getting pushed to your destination Virtual DIR and also try with "~/Content/Some.Doc" if content is placed at root of Virtual DIR.

Comment: Same problem (404.0 - Not Found) with ~/Content but it did give me the idea to check my _Layout and see how I was using css files to come up with the solution (<a href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CAL.doc")">11</a>) I got rid of the "-" just in case.  Since your idea lead to the solution if you add this onto your answer then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I did find that when I was publishing it that it didn't publish the file so I had to manually copy it into the correct location, maybe this is indication explaining why it was so difficult to locate the file when i was running the project locally.

Comment: You have to set Build Action = Content in Properties window of your doc file, later whenever you do build/publish that doc file will be put in appropriate folder.

Comment: I had actually tested that so maybe that was the tipping point but I don't have time to double check now so I'll get back to you when I know but that most likely is the root cause.

Comment: By default it was already set that Build Action = content but I'd changed it in an attempt to fix the previous issue.