# Issues in loading pdf file in browser Play Framework(Scala)

Tags: scala, pdf-generation, playframework-2.1, pdfbox

I'm generating pdf file in my project using pdfbox api,initially i just stored the dynamically generated pdf file in my server and  now i'm trying to stream pdf file in browser with following code

```
 Ok.stream(Enumerator.outputStream { os => 
          doc.writeToStream(os)//doc holds content of pdf file
          os.close()
        }).withHeaders(
          CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/pdf",
          CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "attachment; filename=report.pdf"
        )
```

i have some response begins as

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Version /1.4
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
```

hope it looks like pdf file have generated ,but doesnt load in browser ..i dont know what i'm missing,i just want to load pdf file new tab

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: @barnesjd ya i tried chrome,safari,firefox...but no one worked..

Comment: "Doesn't load in Browser": Does that mean the browser does not download anything at all or that it's just downloaded an not displayed?

Comment: @adhominem im not downloading anything here...just try to open dynamically generated pdf in browser

Comment: Well, but the browser has to download first before it can display

Comment: Can you capture the bytes actually send to the browser in the response? I suspect that would be revealing (fiddler2 would do it, or wireshark). And you are downloading something - the browser is downloadinf the pdf so it can display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your CONTENT_DISPOSITION to "inline":

```
Ok.stream(Enumerator.outputStream { os => 
      doc.writeToStream(os)//doc holds content of pdf file
      os.close()
    }).withHeaders(
      CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/pdf",
      CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "inline; filename=report.pdf"
    )
```

And see if it makes a difference.

It should, even though the specific behavior is browser dependent.

You can find more details regarding the Content-Disposition header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment).

Comment: i just solved now...few problems in js about handling response...now i can open generated pdf in new window...i already tried  CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "inline; filename=report.pdf" ,anyway m accepting ur answer...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Enumerator is not closed properly.

Try this :

```
Ok.stream(Enumerator.outputStream { os => 
      doc.writeToStream(os)//doc holds content of pdf file
      os.close()
    } >>> Enumerator.eof).withHeaders(
      CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/pdf",
      CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "attachment; filename=report.pdf"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
  doc.writeToStream(os)
  os.close
}

Ok.stream(enumerator >>> Enumerator.eof).as("application/pdf")
```

works great in my case too so i suppose there is something wrong with writeToStream. you could do a test by streaming a static image there is nothing special to configure in play framework

Answer (score 0):

The content length attribute in the header is missing .

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream