# How to make open pdf document in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, httpwebrequest, odoo

I work in on openerp when print report I want to make it open inside chrome instead download them.
In version 5 I can do that.

Here is the detail of request and response

Version 5. This is request and response can open pdf inside chrome
[image: Request in Version 5 It can open in chrome instead download them]

In version 7 it request to download 
[image: Version 7 request to download]

Can you give me advice to do that?
Thank for support.

Comment: The key difference here is [the `Content-Disposition` response header.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses)

Comment: but I change it to "Content-Disposition:filename="Analytic Check.pdf"" appear error like that "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf"

Comment: Change it to [`Content-Disposition: inline`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395151/139010).