# Force browser to open file instead of prompting download

Tags: html, hyperlink

When clicking a PDF link in Firefox and Chrome, the file will sometimes be opened for in-browser viewing and sometimes prompt a "Save as" dialog.

If I wanted to force the link to always prompt a download I could use the **download** HTML5 attribute.

However, I want to do the opposite. I.e., **force the links to always be viewed in the browser**.

Sort of an inverse **download** attribute. Is there such a thing? :)

I'd prefer to not modify response headers when serving PDF documents - I want to be able to specify in markup what the browser behavior should be.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force PDF files to open in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-pdf-files-to-open-in-browser)

Comment: My guess is "in browser" viewing is only available through some kind of plug-in. In that case, my recommendation is to ditch PDF altogether and deliver the content using HTML5.

Comment: Weird thing is that **some** PDF files are opened for viewing in the browser, others prompt a download.

The question posted as a possible duplicate doesn't contain any relevant answers since I don't want to append/modify headers. The files are hosted on Amazon S3 and I don't want my app to download them, change the headers and then serve them to the client. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by setting the appropriate header (for instance, in case of PDF, the header will be `Content-type: application/pdf;`

With this header, the browser will know the mime-type of the file and display it if it is compatible with it.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4475) you can see the headers for a PDF.
As a hint, what I like to do is to use some sort of controller (in case you are using a backend language) that handles the download. Hence, to download `myNewProject.pdf` I do

```
<a href='download.php?file=myNewProject.pdf&viewInBrowser=1'>Download!</a>
```

Then I can set the appropriate headers depending on the file type, or if I want to force download or view it in the browser...

Comment: This does not mention the use of `attached`, see older post with similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Firefox in XP. I went to the OPTIONS under Tools and found Portable Document Format. Click on it and it will allow you to change the way PDF files are handled.

Comment: The OP was not asking as a browser user, but as a content provider. He wants people using his site to not download the PDF file, so I'm afraid this will not help him.

Answer (score -13):

open the file in a Microsoft Word and save as html.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want PDF links on **my site** to always be opened for viewing in the visitor's browser as opposed to prompting a download.