# response.setHeader error on google chrome

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, button, response

This is a project on JSP.
1)I have this code where a button is pressed and the action is rendered to another page,which is a JSP page containing a pdf and the user is able to save it.
I had tried my code a month back and it worked fine,now when I try it,it doesnt work on chrome,works on mozilla though.
this is the line of code

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Question.pdf");
```

2)My second problem is that,I have a reset button,this button resets the database.this function works fine on chrome but not on mozilla.I have no idea why it doesnt,there is no action taking place at all.
this is the line of code for that

```
<button type="button" onclick="reset.jsp"><a href="reset.jsp">RESET</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For question 1):
What I know from the difference between `"content-disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.ext"` and `"content-disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext"` is that in the `inline` case the browser will try to render it alone and if it can't it will prompt the user to download it. Maybe in your case you had an extension of Chrome that was capable of showing PDF files in the browser and now not. See [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

As for question 2) :
This code `onclick="reset.jsp"` is not a valid construction. **Onclick** has to be a valid JavaScript function. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp. And it you case it not necessary to have it at all as you have an link inside the button which performs the actual action. I guess Chrome ignores this error and MOzilla not. Try removing `onclick="reset.jsp"` from the button.

Comment: mozilla is able to show and also i can download as pdf,whereas chrome downloads as jsp,actually doesnt download,it gives an error of server failed

Comment: wat should i put then for the 2nd case?

Comment: `<button type="button"><a href="/reset.jsp">RESET</a></button>` should be enough as long as your `reset.jsp` is in the root web directory