# Grails - Displaying PDF in browser rather than downloading

Tags: java, file, grails, outputstream

In my Grails applications, I have a controller function to return a PDF file.

When I make a call to the URL (to return the file), It downloads the file, rather than displaying the PDF file in the browser.

When I open other pdf files from other websites, it displays in browser.. so I think it has something to do with my returned response?

```
def separator = grailsApplication.config.project.separator.flag
def path = grailsApplication.config.project.images.path+"public/"+user.id+"/"
render(contentType: "multipart/form-data", file: new File(path+note.preview), fileName: note.preview)
```

Do I need to change the contentType? (I kind of tried to make it /application/pdf but didnt work?..still downloads.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `content-disposition` to inline. `Content-Type` tells the browser what type of content it is but the disposition tells the browser on how to handle it.

More information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395173/2231632)

Comment: how do i set the content disposition.. when I try  response.setHeader and then call render after, i think it overrides it?

Comment: Can you directly write to the outputstream? Something like:
`response.outputStream << your_file
 response.outputStream.flush()`

Comment: I've tried the following with no luck --->  

response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "inline; filename="+note.preview
  response.contentType = 'application/pdf'
  response.outputStream << new File(path+note.preview)
  response.outputStream.flush()

Comment: I get  "Failed to load document"  so it seems its fetching the file correctly.. but just can't display it properly

Comment: You sure about the content of the PDF file? It opens in Adobe reader when it's sent as an attachment? May be try a different browser?

Comment: I found if I make it "attachment" instead of "inline"... it downloads the attachment.. but when i try open that up.. it says its corrupt.. so it must be the way im returning the output?

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Also, what did you do to fix the 'Failed to load' error? can you update your question with that?

Answer (score 1):

There was something getting corrupt by returning a "File" object rather than a byte[] object.

So I added the following lines.

```
byte[] DocContent = null;
DocContent = getFileBytes(path+note.preview);

response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "inline; filename="+note.preview+""
response.contentType = 'application/pdf'
response.outputStream << DocContent
response.outputStream.flush()


public static byte[] getFileBytes(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
    InputStream ios = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ios = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1)
            ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (ous != null)
                ous.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // swallow, since not that important
        }
        try
        {
            if (ios != null)
                ios.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // swallow, since not that important
        }
    }
    return ous.toByteArray();
}
```