# how to view file pdf in browser without downloading in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

can someone fix my code

this for my Route

```
Route::post('/ViewFile/{nama_file}', 'HSEController@getDownloadFile')->name('DownloadFile');
```

this for my View

```
<a href="{{ route('DownloadFile', $temuan->file) }}" target="_blank">File Lamp</a>
```

and this for my controller

```
public function ViewFile($nama_file)
{

  $file= public_path("/files/".$nama_file);
  $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; '.$nama_file,
     ];

  return response()->file($file, $headers);

}
```

I used that code and the result is file always downloading, I want to change to open in my browser,

Comment: Try it like this: `<a href="{{ route('DownloadFile', $temuan->file) }}" target="_blank">File Lamp</a>` Now it'll give you a option to download and print both in new window!!

Comment: Nope sir, still not working @HirenGohel

Comment: Also make this changes in your controller code: https://pastebin.com/QG2UDfTw

Comment: not work too @HirenGohel

Comment: This is working for me! Please refer this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938294/laravel-display-a-pdf-file-in-storage-without-forcing-download/25938629

Comment: Is it working now??

Comment: nope @HirenGohel

Comment: Have you checked that answer??

Comment: yes I do,, I try and still not working @HirenGohel

Comment: What will you try? Can you update your question which you tried??

Comment: you can see sir, @HirenGohel

Comment: show me, where you code you say work ? @HirenGohel

Comment: This code is working fine for me! Don't know why it's not work for you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the Content Disposition as inline.

```
return response()->file($file_path, [
  'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'. $file_path .'"'
]);
```

Comment: With the use of above code, if the PDF still being downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function ViewFile($nama_file)
{

  $file= public_path("/files/".$nama_file);
  $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; '.$nama_file,
     ];

  return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    //do something here
     }, $file, $headers);

}
```