# laravel how to display pdf in any page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

How can I display a PDF in a Laravel View like I can display a normal image?

The code I am using to implement an image is:

```
<div class="u-img">
    <img 
        src="image/{{ Auth::user()->photo_jpeg }}" 
        alt="profile"
    />
</div>
```

What options/HTML-tags can I use to display a PDF?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938294/laravel-display-a-pdf-file-in-storage-without-forcing-download

Answer (score 0):

you could use an object

```
  <object data="/path/to/pdf.pdf"  type="application/pdf">

  </object>
```

Comment: this code was created  pdf, downloading i need to display pdf in view

Comment: an object does not download, i have removed the fallback

Comment: when i refresh the page it downloading window popups and pdf not displayed

Comment: are you sending any Content-Disposition header in the controller?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0):

you could use an iframe

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/pdf-sample.pdf" id="pdf_display_frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: you do no that the uploads directory is not restricted? i am viewing all the images in the uploads directory

Comment: https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/apache/115/htaccess-file-dir-security.html have look here

Comment: @sunny bhadania                                                                                                                             <iframe src="WEBSITE-FILE/pdf.pdf" id="pdf_display_frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>                                                                                         this code not showing my pdf file it just showing  "iframe"  margins

Comment: @RamuRamu Please give me your pdf path?

Comment: @sunny bhadania                                                                                                             my pdf path  "public/WEBSITE-FILE/pdf.pdf"   i am running this project in localhost

Comment: @RamuRamu Please try this code:- <iframe src="{{ asset('WEBSITE-FILE/pdf.pdf')}}" class="pdf-spacing-verify pdf-view-for-mainnet-verify" id="pdf_display_frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>

Comment: @sunnybhadania not working  just showing empty page

Comment: @RamuRamu Please past this code and check :- <iframe src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" class="pdf-spacing-verify pdf-view-for-mainnet-verify" id="pdf_display_frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>

Comment: @sunny bhadania                                                                                                               not working but i created basic index.html page and added your code that time it worked but in laravel 5.8 its just showing empty page with black borders

Comment: @RamuRamu : Please check :- <iframe src="{{URL::to('/WEBSITE-FILE')}}/pdf.pdf" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>

Comment: Please give me your blade file, controller file and routes web link?

Comment: @sunny bhadania  my blade and controller and rout @include('header')
<iframe src="WEBSITE-FILE/test.pdf" class="pdf-spacing-verify pdf-view-for-mainnet-verify" id="pdf_display_frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
 @include('footer')                                                                                            public function dashboard()
   {
       return view('dashboard');
   }                                                                                                      Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard');

Comment: @sunny bhadania you get any idea