# Returning file response from an external API call in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this method in my controller where I'm calling an external URL that returns a PDF file:

```php
public function get()
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
      ->get('https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf')
      ->body();

    return $response;
}
```

**routes/api.php**:

```php
Route::get('/file', [FileController::class, 'get']);
```

Calling that route in the browser displays this gibberish output instead of the actual file:
[image]

If I do `return response()->file($file)`, it's throwing an error:

> Symfony \ Component\ HttpFoundation\ File \ Exception\ FileNotFoundException

Is there any way to achieve it without having to store the file first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - display a PDF file in storage without forcing download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938294/laravel-display-a-pdf-file-in-storage-without-forcing-download)

Comment: @sta Already tried it. Not working

Answer (score 3):

To send a file response without storing the file locally you an use [`streamDownload`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#streamed-downloads):

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
      ->get('https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf')
      ->body();
}, 'c4611_sample_explain.pdf');
```