# Spreadsheet generated in spring has the wrong extension

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am trying to generate an Excel spreadsheet from spring application. It is getting generated with a .do extension instead of .xls. But if I rename the downloaded file to .xls, I can see all my content available in Excel. My controller code is below.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="getReportsList.do")
    public ModelAndView getReports(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("ordCommand") OrdCommand ordCommand,
        BindingResult errors) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    List<Object[]> recordsArray = null;


    try {

        List<ReportVO> recordsArray = ordService.getDCTrackReports();


        if (null != recordsArray ) {
            //excel formatting code
        }

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "my_report.xls");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    //  ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()
        if (byteArrayStream != null) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(byteArrayStream.toByteArray());
        }
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        byteArrayStream.flush();
        byteArrayStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the Content-Disposition header:

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline:filename=\"my_report.xls\"");
```

The differences between "inline" and "attachment": [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

The Content-Disposition Header https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266

Answer (score 1):

Add filename in Content-Disposition and add make it as attachment and add content type to response with attachment,

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=my_report.xls");
 response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

This will for for sure.