# Streaming playback from Azure Blob Services without Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have added a video tag into my HTML5 page using the Player Framework (http://playerframework.codeplex.com/). I am using the latest version of the Azure Storage Library for my Storage Account. I've seen some alluding to the possibility of HTML5 video playback streaming the file but, in my case, it just seems to download the entire 800MB file before it starts playing. The content type is marked as video/mp4. This happens in the latest Chrome/IE/Edge. Am I missing something here? Are Media Services required for this functionality?

```
<video id="myVideo" class="pf-video" width="480" height="320" controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://.../BuildTourTO_mid.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you verify that the file was upload to azure storage as Block Blob instead of Page Blob?

Comment: Thanks Bruno - it is, indeed, a Block Blob

Comment: Make sure that the `Content-Disposition` is not set as `attachment` on your blob or try setting it as `inline`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment