# Error generating PDF on Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, pdf, itext

I am generating PDF document using iText API in Java. It is running fine on Mozila and MSIE. But when I am removing,

```
response.setHeader("content-disposition: attachment", "inline; filename=myFile.pdf");
```

this part of code from my servlet it is running fine on Chrome as well. But as soon as I add this code and try to run it on Chrome it is giving me error saying 'Failed to load PDF document'.

I need to use above part of code in order to give dynamic name to each PDF generated. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be

```
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=myFile.pdf");
```

or instead of `inline` you can use `attachment`, but not both. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395173/733760).