# Use of (“Content-Disposition”, “inline; filename=” + fileName +"") not showing the file name

Tags: content-disposition

file name: abc.aspx

my code:

```
string Path = @"E:\documents\Data20160129110355.xls";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Data20160129110355.xls");

HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(Path);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

On click of "Open" it will open the file successfully but the header of the file are not showing "Data20160129110355.xls". It's showing abc.aspx.

How to solve this problem please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

[Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

replace 'inline' with 'attachment'.

UP: try this:

HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Data20160129110355.xls");

Comment: It is a good practice to provide a gist of the content in the provided link as part of the answer.

Comment: But not the same results, inline will show the file (eg a PDF, JPG, etc) in the browser window for viewing purposes.

An Attachment, will force the file to be downloaded to the file system, which if you just want to see the graphic, is a waste of time.