# How to make a video file playable on web browser

Tags: html, video-streaming

Im trying to make video files playable from web browser. I upload the files in different repositories but when I click the videoFile it starts to download instead of be played.

This is my resource, when I put this url on the browser the video starts to download.
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsampledatabucket/Media/SampleVideo.mp4

What I want is that when I put the url the video starts playing like this:
https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

Comment: The url you're clicking should be pointing to a web page that contains your video and specify the 'autoplay' attribute on your video tag. Check http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp for more info