# MS Office 2007+ static file download on JSF with IE7+

Tags: jsf, static, download

Got this code:

```
<h:outputLink title="#{msg.fileUpload_template_file}" styleClass="FormSubmitNoColor" type="application/vnd.ms-excel" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/csvTemplates/02_myfile_V1.xlsx" >#{msg.fileUpload_template_file}</h:outputLink>
```

This code work fine for FF but IE thinks this is a zip file. why?

Found the mime type here [Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)
but doesn't work to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, only the mime types which are listed in servletcontainer's own `web.xml` (such as the `/conf/web.xml` one in Tomcat), are recognized and supported based on the file extension.

The `.xlsx` extension is relatively new and not supported by older servletcontainers. You can however define custom mime types in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

If you have full admin control over the servletcontainer, you can of course also add it over there, such as Tomcat's `/conf/web.xml` file.

That it works in FF is because FF will determine by itself based on the file extension against the client-specific mime type mapping ("file associations" as it is called in Windows), when the HTTP `Content-Type` response header of the file download is absent or overly generic.

The related question which you found there applies to `.xls` files only (and is already by default supported by most of the current servletcontainers). You can find an overview of all new Office 2007 OpenXML file mime types here: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php