# How to create a MSEXCEL file using PHP

Tags: php

Good day,

How do i create an msexcel file using php script?
I have already prepared my data in a well structured array. I need
to be able to format my array into tables in msexcel.

the server where the WAMP server is running has no MS Office installed, would it
affect my objective to create the msexcel file. do i need to install on msoffice
in the server in case? fyi, i dont actually need to save the excel file in the server
but can be an option too.

thanks.

Comment: Please find very good answers at [Alternative for PHP_excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

Comment: Consider whether you actually need an Excel file - will a CSV do the job?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a spin on DaveRandoms comment.

Make a CSV and set the mimetype to any of the ones in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document).

That way Excel (or any equivalent application) will start and show the file.

Answer (score 0):

[The PHPExcel library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) will let you take your data and write it into a valid Excel file, whether you need old-style XLS or new style XLSX format.

You don't need to have Excel installed on the server to use it.