# Generate Excel file, but do not save to the server

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel file **`file.xlsx`**. I open this file with PHPExcel and insert my datas:

```
$excel2->getActiveSheet()
                    ->setCellValue('A2', $rowCardCode['podpodrazd'].", ".$rowCardCode['schet'])
                    ->setCellValue('C2', $rowCardCode['tovar_name'])
                    ->setCellValue('C3', $rowCardCode['edinica_izmer']);
```

After, I can save generated file with new name (`temp/New_file.xlsx`).

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('files/temp_file/card/card_'.time().'.xlsx');
```

**I don't want to save generated file to the server. I just want generate Excel file and give it to user for downloading.**

Is it possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpexcel to download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566196/phpexcel-to-download)

Comment: I have get an error to open file

Comment: Post the error you getting.

Answer (score 3):

The `01simple-download-xlsx.php` example in the PHPExcel /Examples folder shows exactly how to do this

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

instead of

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('files/temp_file/card/card_'.time().'.xlsx');
```

But make sure that you're not outputting anything else at all to the browser

Comment: error's message in russian: **"Не удается открыть файл "01simple.xlsx", так как формат или расширение этого файла являются недопустимыми. Убедитесь, что файл не поврежден и расширение его имени соответствует его формату."** . In english translated by Google translater: **"Can not open file "01simple.xlsx", as the format or extension of this file are not valid. Make sure that the file is not corrupted and the expansion of its name match its format."**