# PHPExcel error while saving

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel for exporting a report.

It's gave me an error when I run it on internet (using PHP 5.6)..

But, when I'm test on my localhost, it's fine. Works perfectly (using PHP 5.4.31)

Here's my code

```
function downloadExcelBrand($brand,$tglAwal,$tglAkhir)
{

    $this->load->library('php_excel');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    // print_r($objPHPExcel);die();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', "Concept");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', $brand);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A2', "Period");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', $tglAwal." to ".$tglAkhir);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', "Boutique");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B5', "Q1");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C5', "Q2");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D5', "Q3");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E5', "Q4");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F5', "BBC Score");

    $data = $this->surveymodel->getDataLaporanBrand($brand,$tglAwal,$tglAkhir);
    // print_r($data);die();
    $i = 5;
    foreach ($data as $index=>$value) {
        // print_r($data[$index+1]);die();
        if( $index%4 == 0){
            $i++;
            // print_r($value["Score"]);print_r($value['TotalData']);die();
            $AvgQ1 = $value["Score"] / $value['TotalData'];
            // print_r($AvgQ1);die();
            $AvgQ2 = $data[$index+1]["Score"]/$data[$index+1]['TotalData'];
            $AVGQ3 = $data[$index+2]["Score"]/$data[$index+2]['TotalData'];
            $AvgQ4 = $data[$index+3]["Score"]/$data[$index+3]['TotalData'];
            $BSC = $AvgQ1+$AvgQ2+$AVGQ3+$AvgQ4;

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$i, $value["boutiqueID"]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$i, $AvgQ1);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$i, $AvgQ2);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, $AVGQ3);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$i, $AvgQ4);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$i, $BSC);
        }
    }

    // Instantiate a Writer to create an OfficeOpenXML Excel .xlsx file
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
    // Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    // It will be called file.xls
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Report_By_Brand.xlsx"');
    // Write file to the browser
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

the weird things happen when I remove the `$objWriter->save('php://output');` code. It's asking for saving the excel, but the excel file can't be open because it's corrupted..

*EDIT

- The error is

  This site can’t be reached
  The webpage at http://my-link-in-here might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
  ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

*UPDATE

- I try to add `ob_end_clean();` or `ob_clean();` before `$objWriter->save('php://output');` and it saving the Excel, but I can't open it because Excel says "File Format or File Extention is not valid".
- I try to change the `xlsx` extension to `xls` on `filename` properties, and the Excel now can be opened. But It shows php error `Message:  ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete`
- I try to keep the extension but I deleted the `ob_end_clean();`, and the error comes again..

*Solution :

- I changed the code to be `Excel5` like this

  ```
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"');
  ```

  And it works like champion. Anyone can make a explanation ? I will give the solution to the one who can make the explanation

Comment: what does the error says?

Comment: here's the error @Beginner `This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://the-link-in-here might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Comment: I can't provide an explanation: but perhaps if you looked in your log files, or opened the file generated in a text editor to see if it contained any error messages, it might provide you with an explanation

Comment: The generated file that can't be opened ? I have by changed the extension to `xls` and open it using excel. It shows php error `Message:  ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete` @MarkBaker

Comment: So remove the `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: yap. you're right sir @MarkBaker but, when I remove `ob_end_clean()`, the page is not working and error like the first problem

Comment: Perhaps if you looked in your log files, or opened the file generated in a text editor to see if it contained any error messages, it might provide you with an explanation.... I can't guess (though obvious possibilities include timeout or memory issues), but you can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134683/discussion-between-m-argus-chopin-gyver-and-mark-baker).

Comment: Check that you have PHP's zip extension installed and enabled

Comment: Did you mean archives zip extension @MarkBaker ?

Comment: The OfficeOpenXML format is a collection of XML files wrapped in a zip archive, so it needs PHP with the [zip extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

Comment: I'm never used any stuff like that before. All I do just upload my program and code.. Can you give me more clues @MarkBaker ?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and see if there's any plaintext error messages inside that file

Answer (score 5):

Try install ZipArchive Class i.e `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

as it might be the problem for newly formed server.(It was for me)

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: it is an answer for the above problem @wayneOS

Comment: Can confirm this works on 7.4. Worth noting that as per [one of the maintainer's own comment](https://github.com/phpoffice/phpexcel/issues/716#issuecomment-414599543), officially they do not support >=7.1.

Answer (score 4):

I found a fix,go to `Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php` comment out the following lines, php 7 has a wierd return date type so doing this will enable php excel to work in php 7 pronto. any way

```
$saveDateReturnType = PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::getReturnDateType();
PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::setReturnDateType(PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::RETURNDATE_EXCEL);
PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::setReturnDateType($saveDateReturnType);
```

to

```
//$saveDateReturnType = PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::getReturnDateType();
//PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::setReturnDateType(PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::RETURNDATE_EXCEL);
//PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::setReturnDateType($saveDateReturnType);
```

worked for me.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I'm on php7, may be for below versions ob_end_clean will work.

Comment: tnx, you saved my night :-) btw. I'm on php7.2

Answer (score 2):

Saving the `$writer` output to a file and redirecting to it solved my problem

I also set the time limit and memory limit high so that they don't cause any problem

Code:

```
        $writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet); // instantiate Xlsx
        $writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
        //ob_end_clean();
        set_time_limit(500);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $writer->save($filename . ".xlsx"); // save the file to root of project
        redirect('/' . $filename . ".xlsx"); // redirect the user to the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  ob_end_clean()

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Filename.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

Comment: adding `ob_end_clean()` is removing the error and allow the file to be downloaded. But the downloaded file is still can't be opened. It's says, format or file extenstion is not valid

Comment: What if you change
     `header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');`
to 
   `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');`

Comment: Still can't open the file. And it still say the same error @Jordan Sipahutar http://imgur.com/a/ehsT6

Comment: You need to ensure that the file extension that you provide matches the writer, and matches the content type header

Comment: Is there's any wrong code on the header properties from the code that I wrote on the top ?? @MarkBaker ?? I don't understand why this is error on the hosting. Because on my localhost it work perfectly

Comment: I update the question. any changed that I apply to my code have diff effect. But none of them are my solution @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with 4000+ rows. Increasing both memory limit and time limit fixed the problem.

Reason for ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE behavior is that you send xls/x headers but then http error 500 from running out of memory or time.

```php
set_time_limit(120);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
...
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```