# PHPExcel ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE with PHP7.0

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-7

I have a script that creates an Excel file and exports it. This was running fine in PHP5.6 but since upgrading to PHP7.0 this is not working anymore.

I've found a couple related issues where people suggested installing `php7.0-zip`, but this did not solve the issue.

Also getting the same error on different browsers.

It happens after `$objWriter->save('php://output');`

```
require_once 'includes/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'includes/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$title = 'Export'. date('d-m-Y');
$count = $_GET['count'];

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(0);

foreach ($_SESSION['tableheaders'][$count] as $column => $val) {
    $objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $val);
    $objWorkSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, 1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objWorkSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, 1)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('C2C2C2');
}

$lastColumnIndex = 'A';

foreach ($_SESSION['tablerows'][$count] as $row => $innerArr) {
    foreach ($innerArr as $column => $val) {
        $objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row + 2, $val);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);

        $lastColumnIndex = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->getColumnIndex();
    }
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter("A1:{$lastColumnIndex}1");

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='{$title}.xlsx'");

// If I die here, the error does not happen but my Excel file is damaged/empty.

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: For reference [phpexcel-export-not-working-displays-the-website-cannot-be-reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599112/phpexcel-export-not-working-displays-the-website-cannot-be-reached) was a slightly different situation but the same problem and exact solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem, in `PHPExcel v1.8.0` in file `PHPExcel/Calculation/Functions.php` on line 581 there is a `break;` after a `return` statement which is causing an error.

This was fixed in the latest (and last) version 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

**Phpexcel** does't work well with **PHP 7.0**

Try upgrading from **Phpexcel** to **phpSpreadsheet** .

**phpSpreadsheet** works very well with php latest versions .