# Laravel 5 drops "This site can’t be reached" when trying to download file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, php-7

I have Laravel 5.2 and PHP7.

My host works as it should, except links that generate and download **xlsx** files using *Laravel Excel*. These links drop error **"This site can’t be reached"**. All libraries within a project are installed (and I assume that if problem was in libraries, I would get `500s` about missing classes or something like that).

Maybe some php extension is missing? What am I doing wrong?

UPD: the excel function itself works correctly, but site crashes on download

Comment: Found answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384472/generating-and-downloading-an-excel-file-generates-a-err-invalid-response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating and downloading an excel file generates a ERR\_INVALID\_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384472/generating-and-downloading-an-excel-file-generates-a-err-invalid-response)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using laravel homestead to instead missing webserver
1.installed VirtualBox
2.installed Vagrant
3.installed the Homestead Vagrant Box
4.cloned Homestead into my "home" directory
5.ran the bash init.sh command to create my Homestead.yaml file
6.configured my Homestead.yaml file:

Comment: the problem is about laravel-excel not the server