# Is there a way to download pptx file with PHPPresentation?

Tags: php, phppresentation

I am using PHPPresentation for the first time and everything works fine, but I don't want to save file to some destination, I want to download that file through web browser. How to do that?

Please help.

This is code to save file on some destination

```
$oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPresentation, 'PowerPoint2007');
$oWriterPPTX->save(__DIR__ . "/sample.pptx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pptx");
    $oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPhpPresentation,'PowerPoint2007' );
    $oWriterPPTX->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked when I put first two lines on top of page, and last two lines on bottom of the page.

Comment: @AleksandarMilosevic if it works then accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

PHPPresentation should work similiar to PHPExcel.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566196/phpexcel-to-download) question you can use:

```
$oWriterPPTX->save('php://output');
```