# Why my exported excel file in wordpress has html and css in?

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a table from my database to and Excel file with .CSV extension when the user press export button in WordPress. I am able to export the table but when I export, the table also has all the HTML, CSS and JavaScript tags. Can someone please check my code and show me how I can export the file without the html and CSS? I put my code in a short code and then added into the page.  [[Screenshot of my exported Excel file] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjOhQ.png)]
Thanks
Here is my code

```
session_start();

$con = new mysqli("","","","");

require '/home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cbxphpspreadsheet/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;


if(isset($_POST['export_excel_btn']))
{
    $file_ext_name = $_POST['export_file_type'];
    $fileName = "student-sheet";

    $student = "SELECT * FROM students";

    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $student);
        
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Full Name');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Phone');
        $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Course');
        
        $rowCount = 2;
        foreach($query_run as $data)
        {
            $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $data['id']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $data['fullname']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $data['email']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $data['phone']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $data['course']);
            $rowCount++;
        }

        if($file_ext_name == 'xlsx')
        {
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $final_filename = $fileName.'.xlsx';
        }
        elseif($file_ext_name == 'xls')
        {
            $writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);
            $final_filename = $fileName.'.xls';
        }
        elseif($file_ext_name == 'csv')
        {
            $writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
            $final_filename = $fileName.'.csv';
        }
    
    $writer->save($final_filename);
        

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.urlencode($final_filename).'"');

    $writer->save('php://output');  
            
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "No Record Found";
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit(0);
        
     }} 

session_destroy();
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">

                <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
                {
                    echo "<h4>".$_SESSION['message']."</h4>";
                    unset($_SESSION['message']);
                }
                ?>

                <div class="card mt-5">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Export Clients Data into an Excel File</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <form action="" method="POST">

                            <select name="export_file_type" class="form-control">
                                <option value="xlsx">XLSX</option>
                                <option value="xls">XLS</option>
                                <option value="csv">CSV</option>
                            </select>

                            <button type="submit" name="export_excel_btn" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Export</button>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php session_write_close();
```

I tried to export a table from database into an excel file in WordPress using short Code. I am able to export the file but when i open the file, the file also has the html, css and JavaScript from the page in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question (or give u any hints)? [phpexcel to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566196/phpexcel-to-download)

Comment: @KenLee Thank you for the suggestion, I tried all of these options but it is still exporting the excel file with all the html, CSS and other stuff.

Comment: _"I put my code in a short code and then added into the page"_ - shortcode output is part of the page content, so of course you get all the "surrounding" HTML as well. This is really not a good way to do it. You should rather try and set up a custom REST API endpoint, and then make a request towards that, to trigger your actual excel file download.

Answer (score 0):

Terminiate your php script after the second `save()` by calling `exit(0);`.
And make sure no output is send before you send the headers do for the generated file. You can try an `ob_end_clean();` before sending the headers to php://output.
Also see: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/217 for people having the same issues (although it'snot really a problem of the package).