# How do I provide a download for existing Excel with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a generated xls file on my server that I would like to push to the client for download but can't seem to get it working.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$xlsFile = 'test.xls';

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$xlsFile"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");  
exit();
```

My excel file is correct and can be opened if I open it from the server but how can I push this file to the client for download?

Comment: what's the point of th emultiple content-types? It's like saying "I'm a car, I'm a giraffe, I'm a stick of gum". Unless you're doing multi-part mime, an http request reply can only have a single mime type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overdoing it with your "Content-type" headers.  Oh, and you need to actually send the file before `exit()`ing. All you need is

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $xlsFile . '"');
readfile($xlsFile);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this older post on the correct MIME type to send with your upload:

[Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more line

```
$xlsFile = 'test.xls';

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excelapplication/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='$xlsFile'"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");  
echo file_get_contents($xlsFile);
exit();
```

Comment: These content-type headers are wrong.  You only need one - and neither of these three are correct mime type for excel.

Comment: Indeed, stupidly I just copied the OP's. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Sample function.

```
function file_download($filename, $mimetype='application/octet-stream') {
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
// send headers
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 200 OK');
// type
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
// date of modified       
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
    header('ETag: ' . sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename)));
// file size
    header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)));
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
// send file
    echo file_get_contents($filename);
  } else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
  }
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Care to at least attribute the author?

Comment: Sorry. I'm from Russia, hard english :(

Comment: Откуда скопировали код-то?  Хоть бы ссылочку на оригинальный источинк добавили бы.