# firefox and chrome save the report in .htm format instead of .xls

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I had written a java code to generate a report in .xsl, As it works fine in IE browser but when it comes to firefox or chrome, it save the report in .htm format instead of .xls format. while opening it directly it open in .xsl in all the browwser.

Can anyone advice me !!!!!!!!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are setting the MIME Content-Type correctly. Something like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Also see this related post: [Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)

Comment: i had already added response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); in my code as it work proper for IE browser but for some user agent say chrome and firefox its saving in .htm format...Please advice