# difficulty sending Excel Workbook from Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, apache-poi

My project involves creating an HTML page that has a Table and placing a button on the page labelled "Export To Excel". The whole purpose is to convert the Table data into an Excel file that can be downloaded from the servlet. Using JQuery I had no problem collecting all the data from the Table and sending it off to the Servlet using the following code:

```
$("#export").click(function(){
    var head = JSON.stringify({ header: header });
    var table = JSON.stringify({ data: data });
    //Combine the two into on big object
    var obj = head.substring(0,head.length - 1) + "," + table.substring(1,table.length);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ExportToExcel',
            data: obj,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#result').html(thrownError + "<br/><br/>" +
                                          xhr.responseText);
            }
        })                      
    });
```

Here's my Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
      String json = "";
      if(br != null){
        json = br.readLine();
      }
      //System.out.println("json: " + json);
      br.close();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      Table table = gson.fromJson(json, Table.class);
      ArrayList<String> header = table.getHeader();
      ArrayList<String[]> data = table.getData();

      XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        //CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
        //create the Header
        XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
        {
            rowhead.createCell(i).setCellValue(header.get(i));
        }

        XSSFRow row = null;
        XSSFCell cell = null;
        String[] temp = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            temp = data.get(i);
            row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
                cell.setCellValue(temp[j]);
            }

        }

        //response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxml");
        //response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        String filename = "data.xlsx";
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(out);  
        out.flush();
        out.close();


    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}

class Table
{
    private ArrayList<String> header;
    private ArrayList<String[]> data;

    public void setHeader(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        header = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getHeader()
    {
        return header;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String[]> value)
    {
        data = value;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the Servlet code, I am easily able to create a Workbook and place in it all the data sent via JSON string.  So far so good.

For a response back from the Servlet I get the following in FireBug:

> **Response Headers**
>   Content-Disposition attachment; filename="data.xlsx"
>   Content-Type  application/vnd.openxml
>   Date  Mon, 03 Mar 2014 20:56:15 GMT
>   Server    Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Transfer-Encoding chunked

Also in FireBug under the Response tab I get a bunch of garbage characters:

[image]

I assume this is an error of some sort. From the JQuery Ajax error function I get: ***SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character***. I don't know what that's about???  The browser doesn't prompt me to save the file anywhere. I tried in both Firefox and IE browsers, and the result is the same.  I've tried changing the ContentType back and forth between: ***application/vnd.openxml*** and ***application/vnd.ms-excel***, but again the result is the same.

Is someone able to show me where I am going wrong? I want the browser to prompt me as to where I want to put the file. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can return an Excel file to Ajax. Just give the user a link to the servlet, or make it an HTML form that submits to the servlet.  Using Ajax is probably half your problem if not the whole problem.

Comment: from servlet you have set mime type for excel file and sending excel file but In ajax call you have set mime type as json this says the response body will contain json so jquery will try to parse the content as json and obviously response is not a valid json so it will throw JSON.parse exception

Comment: Now see!  I learned something new.  Yes I set the mime type in the ajax call to json because I was sending a json string, but I assumed that because the response was a different mime type that ajax would read the content type header and handle it, regardless of what type it was. Obviously I was mistaken.  It looks like I'm going to have to get creative and set up a form on the web page, keep it hidden, and send it programmatically to the servlet. I'll work on it and let you know how things turn out.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder if there is a way to tell ajax what mime type to expect as a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with a really old codebase and the company's policy is "If it aint broke don't fix it", so here's how our servlet response for XLSX Export looks.

```java
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + exportTitle + "_" + fileDate + ".xlsx"); // I noticed you had "/" before and after the filename, try removing that, and add the extension.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); // Our legacy code actually has "application/xlsx" and it works fine - but [other answers indicate better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)
```

... For your AJAX I would try removing `dataType` specification, since your response header defines it, jQuery should just "roll" with it.  I believe the mimeType and contentType are used to define what's sent to the server (which you've seemed to have indicated is working fine), so I wouldn't focus too much on that.

Comment: Thanks for the added header information.  I added them to my code and it definitely works.  In addition, I got rid of the Ajax call altogether and just created a hidden form on the webpage.  The hidden form had a hidden input field named "obj".  I used JQuery to set the value of "obj" to the JSON string, then sent the form to the servlet.  That did the trick.  The export feature is now working properly.  Thanks to everyone who contributed their comments.

Comment: Why would you call this "old codebase" ? Asking to better understand because I'm needing this at 2022 and wondering if I should look for an alternative

Comment: This was posted a lifetime ago, and my expectation was it wouldn't be so stringly-typed if I wasn't on Struts.

Comment: Spring does have some tools to leverage though ... 

`headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +  file.getName() + "\"");headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(responseInputStream.response().contentType()));`