# Content-type xls for Bottle framework

Tags: excel, bottle

I'm using Bottle framework and need to open a excel spreadsheet..

Im wondering what should be the content-type on my return parameters

ie;

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

My Current code-

```
@app.route('/SimpleCSV',method='GET')
def createxls():
   import xlsxwriter
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1','HelloWorld')
    workbook.close()
    return workbook
```

New Code

```
    import StringIO
    import xlsxwriter
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory':True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0,0,'Hello World')
    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)

    print 'Excel file created and now will be returned'
    #response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text.xls'
    f1 = open('text-xls','w')
    f1.write(output.read())

    return
```

How do I open my excel file? Should it be f1 = open('test.xls') and write into it?

working code

```
@bottle.route('/xl')
def create_xls():
    import StringIO
    import xlsxwriter
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory':True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for each in range(100):
        for each1 in range(100):
                worksheet.write(each,each1,"Test")
    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)

    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text1.xlsx'
    return output.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document/1964182#1964182) and other sources, the content-type for Excel files is `application/vnd.ms-excel` for .xls files or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for .xlsx files.

But... from your Bottle route I'm wondering whether you're intending to return a csv file, in which case use `text/csv`.

Furthermore, (I think) you need to serialize `workbook` to bytes (a string) before returning it.  Bottle does not know how to return a `Workbook` object.  (Unless `xlsxwriter.Workbook` exposes an iterator that serializes it to a csv string, which seems unlikely.)

Comment: Thanks,Yes, I need to return a csv file..How do I serialize the workbook to bytes?

Comment: That's really a question about the `xlsxwriter` package, which I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with.  Luckily, a quick search of their docs turned up [this example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_http_server.html#ex-http-server), which I believe is what you're looking to do, too.

Comment: Thanks..I think I'm almost there..It opens a blank xls sheet without any value...I'm not sure if I get this--self.wfile.write(output.read())....How do I open my xls file?..I have given the code above...

Comment: You're welcome!  Really, you're asking a new question here, but from a scan of your newly posted code I see that you're writing the output to a file instead of returning it to Bottle.  Have you tried simply `return output.read()`?

Comment: Great, it worked...How do I pass all the cells, Should I pass a String with a delimiter? I will post it xlsxwriter as well...Thanks very much..it really helped me...

Comment: Happy it helped!  Feel free to accept my answer if you think I answered your original question.  With respect to cells/delimiters, I'm afraid I have no idea how xlsxwriter works or your requirements; I suggest opening a new question so those experts can help you.