# Apache csv file download not in excel

Tags: python, apache, bottle

I have a CSV file thats been hyperlinked. When the user clicks it, its supposed to open in a XLS file but for some reason its opening in HTML page..How can I fix it?

The python bottle application runs on apache webserver.

```
<a id="d14" href="../files/BUY_PRODUCT_LIST.csv">PRODUCT_LIST.csv</a><br>
```

Comment: csv is probably being served up as text/plain. you'd have to serve it up with an appropriate excel mime type, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet, `.xls` with a comma separated value file, `.csv`.

`csv` is just a text file in which tabular data is delimited by a comma (or a tab, a dot, a semicolon, etc). Your browser can handle this file type as a text file and will display it as such.

You will have to modify the HTTP header and change the `Content-Type` to something more fitting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming this to be a link to a static .csv file that is directly linked,  you can modify the 
   mime types definitions on your webserver to set the Content-Type header
   for csv as  ms-xl file type.

   If you are using apache webserver , edit the *mime.types*  file to add the following line:

   application/vnd.ms-excel csv

   of-course then all .csv files would be opened by default in the MS-Excel app.

2.If the file is dynamically generated , then set the response header 'Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel'  in your server side code.