# Download Excel file with Ajax and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

User presses a button contained within a `form` on the page:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="button" id="export" value="Export"/>
</form>
```

Upon clicking the button, the following Ajax call is made:

```
ajaxCall('/export', {}, callback_export, 'get');
```

Where

```
function ajaxCall(url, params, callback, type) {
    if (validate()) {
        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: params
        });
    }
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        callback(response);
    });
}
```

The Flask app looks like this:

```
@app.route('/export')
def export():
    xl_file= '/absolute/path/to/excel/file.xlsx'
    return send_file(xl_file, as_attachment=True, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

The file contents of the file are being returned to the browser (see image below) but not the file itself as an attachment.

Question is, what does the callback need to look like to accept the response as a file attachment? Or otherwise, what modifications need to be made?

(Yes, I've searched and read many of the posts on SE. Most discussing using the `form.submit()` method but do not provide details. I'm hoping to avoid using `form.submit()` as there are other elements within the `#form` that cannot be submitted.)

[image]

Comment: not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) post helps. Try adding a header in your response `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name_of_excel_file.xls"');`

Comment: Thanks I saw that post. Using `as_attachment=True` and `mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel` in the `send_file` method have the same effect (I think).

Comment: [Ajax can't be used to download a file.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/978961)

Answer (score 7):

You really need to use ajax? I found ajax is a work around to download excel files with flask...but it didn't work for me.
I simply open excel file in 'rb' mode and change mimetype to be recognised as excel file in windows. Your Flast only need to call getPlotExcel().

```
@app.route("/getPlotExcel")
def getPlotExcel():
    excelDownload = open("sample.xlsx",'rb').read()
    return Response(
        excelDownload,
        mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=sample.xlsx"})
```

Comment: we need ajax for a complete and success callback. this doesn't answer it

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flask's [`send_from_directory` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory)

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(directory='uploads', filename=filename)
```

Comment: Does this set the mimetime and headers automatically?

Comment: are you saying that ajax and send_file are not compatible with each other? need more context

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach, not Ajax, I have created a function to update the href with some parameter every time a selection changes it, in this case is the country_id.

HTML:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="export-excel" href="#">Download</a>
```

In the script section I wrote:

```
function country_change(country_id)
{
   var param = "/export_excel?";
   param += "country_id=" + country_id;
   $("a[id='export-excel']").attr('href', param);
}
```

So when you click the button the href is already updated. My flask part is:

```
@app.route('/export_excel')
def export_excel ():
     country_id = request.args.get('country_id')
     obj = class_calc.calc()
     file_excel = obj.generate_excel(country_id)
     return send_file(file_excel, as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
```

Works fine.

Comment: this was a very different case IMO, not answering OP at all