# online java application facing issues with excel 2013

Tags: java, excel

Currently the application works as expected with excel 2010 and can able to download reports.But the same application when tried to download using excel 2013 will not work.

The jsp page contains the below snippet. Do i need to add anything to make it work? Please help

```
<%@page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document and try to change contentType to another one.

Comment: Also: Drop the pageEncoding and ensure no white space like a final newline is written `%><% .... %>` (not ending in a newline).

Comment: Tried all possible mime types and removed pageEncoding. still the problem exists.. Please help..

Comment: Please suggest i didn't work