# fpassthru acting weird (sending the page html rather then the file I want)

Tags: php

I'm really really new to PHP, so if you can explain it to me what my code is actually doing and why the result is what it is I would appreciate very much. I'm probably screwing up something very simple.

Basically I want to query a MySQL database, create a csv with the data, and download the csv. Pretty simple. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include("Includes/PHPheader.php");
    $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($query_string);

    $sql = "SELECT many_columns_i_removed_from_this_sample_code FROM table WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();    

    $f = fopen("csv/tmp.csv", "w");
    fputcsv($f, array_keys($row),';');
    fputcsv($f,$row,';');
    rewind($f);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tmp.csv"');
    fpassthru($f);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

There are some HTML code below it that shouldn't affect anything, but just in case here it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Well, I thought this would download my csv with no problem. If I go to the csv folder, there it is, the tmp.csv file I created, with the proper header and data.

But when I open the tmp.csv file I downloaded, it is actually the html code of the page, and not the data I expected.

What is going on?

In case it helps, I'm using WebMatrix 3.0.

Comment: any reason you're writing out to a file anyways? you could just open `php://output` and fputcsv() directly out to the browser.

Comment: No reason, rather than I didn't knew php://output. Made the change, still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on, probably. First, You are trying to read (fpassthru) from a file opened for writing (`fopen(..., "w")`), so You are not able to read anything from the file. Then, after that "reading nothing" goes Your HTML code, which naturally appends to Your output. Try this:

```
$f = fopen("csv/tmp.csv", "w+");
...
fclose($f);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks. The w+ thing didn't work (no idea why). But your explanation makes total sense. So I decided to close $f, than create a $g to open the file on read mode, and it worked like a charm. Not very efficient (saving a file than opening it again), but it worked. That's the most important right now

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try?

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

instead of

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
```

I have a test code of CSV output, have a look - https://foowms.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stockincsv.php

A very informative thread of Stack Overflow
[Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)

==============================================

If csv file open, write and save, then you should do as follows-

```
$list = array ("Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway");
$file = fopen("csv/tmp.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line) {
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
}

fclose($file);
```

==============================================

You also could try this

`fputcsv($fp, array_values($list), ';', ' ');`

instead of

`fputcsv($f, array_keys($row),';');`

Comment: No luck, still the same issue

Comment: And it is just an csv

Comment: Have a look on google code link. May be you will get some idea.

Comment: Took a look, nothing rang a bell. You are creating the whole text in a $csv_output variable then printing it. I'm trying to create a csv file with fputcsv() and then downloading it. I really wish to understand what I'm doing wrong. But if I don't succeed, I'll go with your approach