# Writing a excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am generating an Excel file serverside, which returns a string like this:

```
PKDì@zGÚÝ×¾zdocPropDs/app.xmlAkã0SïýF÷FvXdîÃ.
$mÏª<EdIh¦&é¯¯ì×iö´>½y<}IÜAZuÑxW²b³öq»=oßÞ±I¹JYï dG@v/oÄ:ú`¬!
ÎQ7Ð*¥±KÚÇVQ*ãûº6½~oÁçùOWAuÆ@vJ\tô¿¡×=¾l!åIñ5ZQúIù×èèÑ×ý:h°O"m@¿GCG>-ÅF+Ë,keÿj¨~gke"JÑÑ¢M>fh>ÒÖæ,{S=NÉ:rÄN¶S1h¢|õq
......
```

Headers

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report.xlsx
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8; header=present
```

Can I take this and create an executable Excel file?

Comment: You need to send this content with an appropriate `content-type` header. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964182/125816

Comment: I am sending it with the following headers

Comment: I dont see how. I need to take the raw body and create a file, but when I try to do so, Excel complains about the file being unknown

Comment: "when I try to do so" - how are you doing that?

Comment: I copy the above (full) data into a file called report.xlsx and saves it. Excel then complains about the file being damaged

Comment: Those headers should make the browser prompt to save file `report.xlsx` instead of showing binary garbage on the page. Must be you're not sending them correctly.

Comment: are you using the Roo gem ?