# JMeter - Specified Content-Type Not Being Respected

Tags: jmeter, mime-types

I'm trying to perform an Export of a spreadsheet and save it off as a proper .xlsx file.

The HTTP Header Mgr is configured as:

```
`Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1`
`Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
```

I am using a Listener, Save Responses to a File, under the HTTP Request where

```
'Filename prefix: ~/results/ExportResults_'
'Add Timestamp: enabled
```

Each time I run the HTTP request, the file is output as *ExportRequestResults_20160308-1305_1*.**octet-stream** instead of **.xlsx**.

Based on my searching through the multiple threads on StackOverflow regarding exporting to a spreadsheet (e.g., [Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)), I believe the MIME type correct.  But just as a sanity check, I changed the MIME type to `application/vnd.ms-excel` and still received the same results. (i.e., octet-stream)

Anyone have any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `octet-stream`, you can set the file extn explicitly.

Save it as xls / xlsx. Do not let JMeter add any suffix/prefix.

[image]