# Paperclip validation not working for excel file for Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, paperclip, content-type

So I'm allow many types of file to be uploaded (pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx and zip) using Paperclip.

So far so good, everything works fine.
Except one thing. I noticed that the *.xls file where not uploaded.

Here my model `Document`

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file

  validates_attachment_content_type :file,
    content_type: [
      "application/pdf",
      "application/vnd.ms-excel",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      "application/msword",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
      "application/zip"]
end
```

I'm using S3 and this issue is happening in local and production (heroku). I kind of heard that it could be linked to the browser itself; however, I did test on (under os x) Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera without success.

Here the log when I try to upload a xls file name `this-is-a-test-file.xls` :

`Started POST "/documents" for ::1 at 2016-08-26 01:41:54 +0200
Processing by DocumentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GdnkT1Iw8ajORrrSidpQ4Un4qlcN7qzZFk00j3fTTe0VpDO4ZhGQQG0ckO5DmrDzDdqzLw5SXI+O3p72zuP6qQ==", "document"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdcc5479b78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/gc/r_620xsx5hs44l70ftvwxpjr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160826-79534-4kin0o.xls>, @original_filename="this-is-a-test-file.xls", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[file]\"; filename=\"this-is-a-test-file.xls\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}, "commit"=>"upload file"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/gc/r_620xsx5hs44l70ftvwxpjr0000gn/T/99ca719bb8fc2d3a1543726223f4d54520160826-79534-10bpmb.xls'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/gc/r_620xsx5hs44l70ftvwxpjr0000gn/T/99ca719bb8fc2d3a1543726223f4d54520160826-79534-176ftj5.xls'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/documents
Completed 302 Found in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)`

Any idea ? :)

Comment: I also tried to add `Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls, [], %w(xls)` in `mime.types.rb` however it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you try to add all the mime type listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document in your validate_attachment_content_type method.

Comment: @Typpex that's what I did but did not work.