# PHP output Excel-The file format and extension don't match

Tags: php, excel

I have made a script that outputs a XLS file with data brought from my database. Problem is that when you view the file on OSX and Linux it looks as it is supposed to.

**Behaviour on Windows**

On Windows excel shows the following message.

> The file format and extension 'nameofthefile.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust.....

Have you ever faced this problem?

```php
$sql    = "MY SQL QUERY";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output .= '<table class="table" border="1"
                <tr>
                <th>MY Table heads</th>
                <th>MY Table heads</th> 
               </tr>';

    $count = 1;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data        = strtotime($row['reg_date']);
        $format_date = date("d.M.Y", $data);

        $output .= '
                    <tr>
                    <td>' . $count++ . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>
                       <td>' . $row["firstname"] . '</td>
                          <td>' . $row["lastname"] . '</td>
                                  <td>' . $format_date . '</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';

    header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=download.xls");

    echo $output;


    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it could be the reason, but there's a typo in your code. `header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=download.xls");` should be `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");`

Comment: Fixed the typo. The problem is still reproducing...Also thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'd try with another Content-Type, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document

Comment: Tried. Same result. Also I have removed parts of HTML to have it as rudimentary as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem using Laravel with http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs and i solve the problem by checking if there was a clean code, i had a apostrophe (') character somewhere in my code and when i detected it i just erased that character and the file was exported with success. Good luck!

Comment: I found this.Which basically says that its because we try to add HTML in the excel file http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114584/warning-propmt-on-downloaded-excel-file-format-and-extension-do-not-match-the

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this package for laravel and after researching, i knew that the problem was the web.php file's encoding! in my case Encoding file was UTF-8-BOM and when changed it to UTF-8 problem solved!
i did it with notepad++