# export html table using javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using the following codeto export html table using javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //getting data from our table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('history');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'exported_table_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + '.xls';
    a.click();
    e.preventDefault();});});
```

This works well on Chrome and Firefox. But in IE11 when I click the export button I am getting

The webpage cannot be displayed

Most likely cause:
•Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: "_Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed_" That's it, how could we help?

Comment: add table id .. do not add div id  here ->var table_div = document.getElementById('history');

Comment: I am already using the table ID : <table class="table table-striped" id="history">

Comment: Maybe IE is more exquisite accepting excel MIME type, try other options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document

Comment: I tried all the MIME. None worked for me in IE                                    
 The webpage cannot be displayed

Most likely cause: •Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.

Comment: @Teemu I am just trying to pull the table in Excel. I am MS office installed. This script works in Mozilla and Crome. I am having issue only in IE.

Comment: In windows 10 when i click export button in IE it tries to open an app in app store : Results for "data". Any idea why is it trying to open as "data" rather than XLS ?