# How to export excel file from php

Tags: php, excel, export

I want to remove warning ([warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqTGS.png))
P.S I know that .xls is old version and I'm trying to use .xlsx but don't working.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');
$data = "Some utf-8 characters Ä…Ä‡Å¼ÅºÄ‡Å‚";
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "Export '.date("Y-m-d").'.tsv"'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=municipaliteties_list.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: remove duplicated headers first. header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");  , header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8'); , header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "Export '.date("Y-m-d").'.tsv"');  and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964182/2585154

Comment: And also your MS Excel is showing a warning because you are trying to open a file with ".xls" extension but its content is not in XLS format.

Comment: And what should I do now?

Comment: Still don't working. 


header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=municipaliteties_list.xlsx");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

Comment: @NikaKachibaia you have to use a 3rd party library like PHPSpreadsheet for excel files generation. The code you shared just displays html in xls format and it is not actual xls content.

Comment: @UmarSharjeel Can you help me. how to solve this problem.

Comment: @NikaKachibaia use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I haven't composer

Comment: Is any other idea?

Comment: @NikaKachibaia first of all install Composer - https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md , after that install this library https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet#installation , after that read the docs - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and look at examples, e.g. - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Basic/01_Simple_download_xlsx.php