# How to solve " No converter for XXX with preset Content-Type ‘application/octet-stream；charset=UTF-8‘ "

Tags: java

When I encapsulated the interface logic for downloading excel in the background, the response returned success after the file stream was closed, but the background reported an error

I ran into a problem when I tried to use a tool or library with the following error message:

> No converter for XXX with preset Content-Type 'application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8'

I'm trying to do some kind of conversion or processing operation, but I can't find a suitable converter. The error appears to be content-type related and specifies "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" as the default content type.

How to solve this problem so that I can successfully complete the operation? What tool or library am I using? Do I need to configure or add specific converters? Are there other possible solutions?

Please provide detailed steps and sample code so that I can better understand and try to solve this problem. Thank you!

Error message:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.foxconn.common.beans.ResultBean] with preset Content-Type 'application/octet-stream'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
```

When I encapsulated the interface logic for downloading excel in the background, the response returned success after the file stream was closed, but the background reported an error

Comment: The root cause seems to be around MIME type, for which your infrastructure is not prepared to handle Excel files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964182/1111895

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the problem and found that some of the reasons for the problem were the response logic of the whole package of my system, so I also returned the success and failure logic after downloading the file. But it doesn't support

---

Solution: Add a converter！it does work and solves the problem！

**Here is a reference code:**

```java
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
           
    FastJsonHttpMessageConverter convert = new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();
           
    FastJsonConfig config = new FastJsonConfig();
            
    config.setSerializerFeatures(SerializerFeature.PrettyFormat,
    SerializerFeature.WriteNullStringAsEmpty,
    SerializerFeature.WriteNullNumberAsZero,
    SerializerFeature.WriteNullListAsEmpty,
    SerializerFeature.WriteNullBooleanAsFalse,
    SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue,
                  
    SerializerFeature.DisableCircularReferenceDetect);
    config.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    config.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    convert.setFastJsonConfig(config);
    convert.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedMediaTypes());
    converters.add(convert);
}

public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {

    List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_RSS_XML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_MARKDOWN);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.ALL);
    return supportedMediaTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the response Content-Type to application/octet-stream,
But what you responded to was a custom object ResultBean. Spring tried to convert the ResultBean object into a response body in application/octet-stream format, but did not find a suitable converter, so it threw an HttpMessageNotWritableException.

```
@GetMapping("/common/download")
public void download(HttpServletResponse httpServletReesponse){
    try {
        // ... download
    } catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        httpServletResponse.reset();
        ResultBean<T> result = new ResultBean<>(HttpSStatus.ERROR, e.getM
        String str = JSON.toJSONString(result);
        ServletUtils.renderString(httpServletResponse, str)
    }
}
public static void renderString(HttpServletResponsse response, String str){
            try {
                response.setStatus(200);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                response.getWriter().print(string);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```